# Xamarin.Android hyperlink in middle of text not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, textview, fromhtml

**Goal**: Have a word in the middle of a sentence be a hyperlink that opens the website in a browser

**What's happening**: It looks like a hyperlink, but nothing happens when I click

**What I've tried**:

- I tried making it an intent, that worked to make it clickable, but it made the entire
  sentence clickable.
- Also, I then switched to using the Html.FromHtml method.

**C#**:

```
string Content = "<span>Please navigate to <a href='https://www.website.com'>HERE</a> to register</span>";
lblTESTSystem.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml(Content); //lblTESTSystem.SetText(Html.FromHtml(Content, FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

**What the above code looks like**:

[image]

Alternate/first C# code that made entire sentence clickable:

```
//lblTESTSystem.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => 
//{
//    var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.website.com");
//        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
//        StartActivity(intent);
//};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `WebView` in the xaml page then bind a `html file` to the `WebView.source`.

In the MainPage.xaml, you can add the code to the target page.

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
```

In the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webView.Source = "file:///android_asset/name.html";
        }
    }
```

Then Create the `name.html file` in the target file package.

```
 <html>
    <body>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

       <span>Please navigate to <a href='https://www.website.com'>HERE</a> to register</span>

    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: If you have questions please feel free to ask.